# Why isn't the background colour changing? (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, switch-statement, rgb

I'm new to programming, and stackoverflow, so I apologize if my question isn't in the correct format.

I'm working with code which was partially written by my professor, with directions included from him in comments. My goal is to get the javascript to write CSS in order to change the background colour of the page. I think the problem is with the second function (writeCSS), but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Here's the code I've got. Sorry for the massive block of code, I don't want to leave out anything that might be needed.

Any other general tips or criticism would be great!

```
/* Declare and initialize global variables
-------------------------------------------------- */
const pageBg = document.querySelector('html');
const sliders = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
let rgb = [0, 0, 0];

/* Event handlers for range sliders
-------------------------------------------------- */
for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i ++) {
    // Loop through the three range inputs and for each one, add an onchange event listener
    
    sliders[i].onchange = function() {
        // If an input range slider is moved, grab it’s id attribute value

        let whichSlider = this.getAttribute('id');
        // …also, grab the numerical value that it is set to

        let sliderValue = this.value;
        // Declare a new variable to hold the new RGB value that calls a function that updates the global rgb variable, passing in what slider was moved (whichSlider), and its value (sliderValue)

        newRgb = changeRgb(whichSlider, sliderValue);
        // Call a function that builds a new CSS background-color property (as a string), passing it the updated RGB array (newRgb)

        let newCSS = writeCSS(newRgb);
        // Directly change the background-color of the page using the new CSS rgb value

        pageBg.style.backgroundColor = newCSS;
    };
};

/* Functions
-------------------------------------------------- */
// STEP 1: Write a function called changeRgb() that accepts two parameters, channel and value
function changeRgb(channel, value) {

    // STEP 2: Build a switch based on the value of the channel parameter (red, green, or blue) (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

    switch(channel) {
    // STEP 3: Inside each case, update the appropriate global rgb array element (0, 1, or 2)   

        case "red":
            rgb[0] = value;
            break;
        case "green":
            rgb[1] = value;
            break;
        case "blue":
            rgb[2] = value;
            break;
    }
    // STEP 4: Return the updated rgb array back to the event handler

    return rgb;
}

// STEP 5: Write a new function called writeCSS() that accepts one parameter, the updated rgb array
function writeCSS(newRgb) {

    // STEP 6: Declare a new local variable called newColor that will contain the new string that will be used to update the CSS background-color property in the following format: rgb(0,0,0) - initialize it with the start of the string, 'rgb('

    let newColor = "rgb(";
    // STEP 7: Create a while loop that iterates through the array passed into this function, called newRgb (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)

    let i = 0;
    while(i < newRgb.length) {
        // STEP 8: For each element of the array, add to the string newColor, the red, green, and blue values, each followed by a comma

        newColor += newRgb[i]; 
        newColor += ",";
        i++;
    }
    // STEP 9: Slice off the last comma from the string contained by the variable, newColor - we don’t need it (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

    newColor = newColor.slice(0, -1);
    
    // STEP 10: Finish off the newColor string by adding the closing ')'
    newColor += ")";

    // STEP 11: Return the string newColor back to the event handler
    return newColor;
}   
// STEP 12: Move the contents of this script element into a separate .js file and add a script element to the head of this html file to connect it - don't forget the defer attribute!
```

I tried to play around with the writeCSS function, as when I try to call it in the console, I get this error: VM717:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: newColor is not defined at :1:1

When the sliders are moved, the background stays black.

I'm at a loss, because I thought `let newColor = "rgb(";` is defining it.

Comment: It works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/2xe3mrLd/

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Strange assignment with a bad example of doing things. https://jsfiddle.net/L1u6josf/

Comment: for review of working code, [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code works, though there are some funny things about the code. Using the `.onchange` property of an element to assign a function feels a bit old school instead of `.addEventListener`. All these formal loops instead of using array methods. Grabbing the attribute `id` from the element every iteration instead of assigning it once in a scope that can be accessed by the function. Using a switch statement instead of using an object as a dictionary to lookup / assign the related values. Having to slice off the last comma especially when it's only three variables that could be pieced together. Probably lots of things that serve to teach the syntax instead of being best practice. I'm also probably nowhere near as accredited as your professor so take my thoughts with a grain of salt.

If you're experiencing issues it could be with your html or the environment you're running the js in. I'm not sure what your project structure looks like. If you have an interest in making a github repo I'd always be happy to review the project.

For reviewing working code you could always check out [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for the feedback others get, or getting feedback of your own.

I did my own take on the color changing idea. I was thinking about packaging it in a way that I might be able to pack it into a component into the future. I have css manage the variables, and just change the css variable based on the slider update. I used the html data attribute to track which input affects which `rgb` value. I decided to listen to the `input` event instead of `change` event, because it gave a more pleasing cosmetic effect.

Good luck out there

```js
const get = (str, parent = document) => [...parent.querySelectorAll(str)];
const container = get(".color-area")[0];
const setUpdate = el => {
  const rgb = el.dataset.rgb;
  const property = `--${rgb}`;
  el.addEventListener("input", () => {
    const val = el.value;
    container.style.setProperty(property, val);
  });
};
get("input", container).forEach(setUpdate);
```

```css
.color-area {
  --r: 0;
  --g: 0;
  --b: 0;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(var(--r), var(--g), var(--b));
}
```

```html
<div class="color-area">
  <input data-rgb="r" type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0" />
  <input data-rgb="g" type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0" />
  <input data-rgb="b" type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0" />
</div>
```